# Issues with wifi – Ubuntu 20.04 – Lenovo S540

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I bought a used Lenovo Ideapad S540 with windows 10. First I installed Ubuntu 20.10 but I could not connect with the internet. Then I installed Ubuntu 20.04.

**The problem:**
When I locked in the wifi shows the networks and trys to connect to my known network. It connects but however after around three seconds there appears an error and no network is shown anymore. If I go to "see hidden networks" I see my known network but it won't do a stable connection.

**What I tried already:**
I installed 20.04 because my roommate and some users said I would work. I'll stay with 20.04 but I tried to install different divers because I think to problem is the driver. So far nothing worked.

Network Controller: Realtek RTL8822BE

Kernel driver in use (and modules): rtw_8822be

Please help me. Btw. I did not use Ubuntu for a couple of years.

Thanks so much